# Error related to keyword 'private'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Help with error says that

> thevoid CalculatorClass::SumComplex(); is private

i add and the second file(not only header) but the problem is still there

**calculator.h**

```
//header file
#include<iostream>

void SumComplec();
void DifComplex();
void MultComplex();
void DivComplex();
```

**calculator.cpp**

```
//i calculate the result of numbers

#include <iostream.h>
#include "calculator.h"

using namespace std;

class CalculatorClass{

    //float r1,i1,r2,i2;

    void SumComplex() {  //add complex numbers

        float sumRe,sumIm;
        float r1,i1,r2,i2;

        cout << "Enter 2 complex numbers: " << endl;
        cin >> r1 >> i1 >> r2 >> i2;  //read nimber
//sum of real and imanige part of number
        sumRe = r1 + r2;
        sumIm = i1 + i2;
        if(sumIm < 0) {
            cout << "Sum is " << sumRe << sumIm << "j" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Sum is " << sumRe << "+" << sumIm << "j" << endl;
        }
    }



};
```

**main.c**

```
#include <iostream.h>        //add header and other file
#include "calculator.h"
#include "calculator.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int choise;
    char op;

    CalculatorClass CalculatorObject;  //i call class

    do {                                                                                /* Elenxos gia swsti eisagwgi epilogis */
        cout << "For complex numbers press 1,for normal numbers press 2!" << endl;
        cin >> choise;
    } while(choise != 1 && choise != 2);

    do {                                                                  /* Elenxos gia swsti eisagwgi telesti */
        cout << "Choose operator:" << endl;
        cin >> op;
    } while(op != '+' && op != '-' && op != '*' && op != '/');


    if(choise == 1) {       //if is '+' i calculate

            if(op == '+') {
                CalculatorObject.SumComplex();
            }


    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You missed the `public` access modifier

Comment: i put it and the problem exists again

Comment: where exactly did you put it? you should put it above `void SumComplex()` function implementation inside calculator.cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

By default member variables and member functions inside a class are private. As such they cannot be referenced directly from outside of the class.

In your case, the member function `SumComplex()` is private and is referenced in the `main`. You need to make it public by writing `public:` before the `SumComplex` definition.

Note that `public:` is a switch that remains relevant for all declarations within the class appearing after it. So, if you add something more beneath `SumComplex` it will be public as well, until you switch explicitly back through `private:`.

Comment: you mean that i must put class into calculator.h and put public at the top ?

Comment: No, within `CalculatotClass` you need to make the `SumComplex` member function public. File structure has nothing to do with it. Why don't you check what "class member visibility" means in C++ book, tutorial or other material you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your class structure should be something like:

**calculator.h**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CalculatorClass{

public:
    //float r1,i1,r2,i2;

    void SumComplex();
    void DifComplex();
    void MultComplex();
    void DivComplex();
};
```

**calculator.cpp:**

```
#include "calculator.h"
void CalculatorClass::SumComplex() {  //add complex numbers

        float sumRe,sumIm;
        float r1,i1,r2,i2;

        cout << "Enter 2 complex numbers: " << endl;
        cin >> r1 >> i1 >> r2 >> i2;  //read nimber
//sum of real and imanige part of number
        sumRe = r1 + r2;
        sumIm = i1 + i2;
        if(sumIm < 0) {
            cout << "Sum is " << sumRe << sumIm << "j" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Sum is " << sumRe << "+" << sumIm << "j" << endl;
        }
    }
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "calculator.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int choise;
    char op;

    CalculatorClass CalculatorObject;  //i call class

    do {    /* Elenxos gia swsti eisagwgi epilogis */

        cout << "For complex numbers press 1,for normal numbers press 2!" << endl;
        cin >> choise;

    } while(choise != 1 && choise != 2);


    do { /* Elenxos gia swsti eisagwgi telesti */

        cout << "Choose operator:" << endl;
        cin >> op;

    } while(op != '+' && op != '-' && op != '*' && op != '/');


    if(choise == 1)
    {       //if is '+' i calculate

            if(op == '+') {
                CalculatorObject.SumComplex();
            }


    }
    else{
        if(op == '+')
            cout<<"Sum Operation"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"Something Else"<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

To test on Mac Terminal:

```
g++ main.cpp calculator.cpp
./a.out
```

It works as expected.

I hope, it will help.

Comment: error again redefination of class

Comment: @Xri, I have modified the code calculator.h class and added main.cpp class as well. I tested the same code on my Mac and it is working great. I hope it will solve your problem now..:)

Answer (score 0):

Your program missing the ' public:' keyword. If you don't include private or public then everything in your class will be count as private. just add a public: in front of your function

Comment: in calculator.h ???  error again if you say this !